# Do NSViewControllers live inside NSWindowControllers?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

Just starting out with learning how to make apps for Mac and I have a question about how `NSViewControllers` and `NSWindowControllers` work together. If I'm understanding this correctly, `NSWindowControllers` are the Objective-C classes that handle all code relating to a specific window that is displayed by my application. `NSViewControllers` are also Objective-C classes that wrap around a certain group of views.

If I'm on the right track so far, would it make sense for me to create a new `NSViewController` for every view/screen I want to swap in and out of my main window? Or should I add my view elements directly into the `NSWindowController` and figure out a way to swap in the individual elements in/out of the window as needed?

Answer (score 0):

Where you put your controller logic depends on the complexity of your application, window, or view. Most simple apps put everything into their application delegate. NSDocument based applications typically put everything into their NSDocument subclass… If you have multiple windows (with non-similar behavior) then it's probably easier to factor their controller code into different NSWindowController sub-classes. You typically don't really need NSViewControllers unless the complexity of a view (or set of views) is more than you want to put into an (perhaps already overloaded) NSWindowController.

In your case where you're swapping in/out big groups of (sub-)views having each (sub-)set of views all working off their own NSViewController would probably simplify things.

In this case the NSWindowController just acts as an NSViewController controller… ;-)